# HTML5 page which returns sensor data from iPhone to server

Tags: html, accelerometer, sensors, gyroscope

for the past few days i was working on a project that uses iPhone's gyroscope to move items on a computer's screen, i use an app called "Sensorlogger" that can stream the sensor data to the computer using UDP; a Java application received that data and converted it to item's positions (i use it for a game called Minecraft); but now i need another thing : i need to have a button on the iPhone to select items on the screen, but the Sensorlogger app doesn't allow this, and i don't have 99$ for a developer's license at Apple so i can make my own app with a button; i want to use HTML5 to retrieve sensor data, but i also want to add a button on screen (just a grey rectangle, it doesn't need to be fancy, just functionnal), but i have absolutely no knowledge in programming (i barely made my Java app) so does someone have sample code of retrieving sensor data and sending it to the server, and to send an event to the server if the virtual button is pressed ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [Ratchet](https://github.com/maker/ratchet) (Prototype mobile apps with simple HTML, CSS and JS components) can help you.